# Unique constraint on two columns irrespective of order

Tags: sql, postgresql, create-table, unique-constraint

I have a pretty simple table:

```
    id  | name   | alternate
--------+--------+------------
     1  |   Joe  |     Joseph
--------+--------+------------
     2  |   Pete |     Peter
--------+--------+------------
```

and so on.

I want to add a constraint on the name and alternate column, but irrespective of order. For example, I don't want to be able to insert `(3, 'Peter', 'Pete')` as that is essentially the same as id 2, just with the columns reversed.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a unique index:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON atable
   (LEAST(name, alternate), GREATEST(name, alternate));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a unique index:

```
create unique index my_unique_idx
on mytable(least(name, alternate), greatest(name, alternate));
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=c1663f9800998b2dbe2d223042630e77)**:

```
create table mytable (name varchar(10), alternate varchar(10));

create unique index my_unique_idx
on mytable(least(name, alternate), greatest(name, alternate));

insert into mytable values('foo', 'bar');
-- 1 rows affected

insert into mytable values('bar', 'foo')
-- ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint &quot;my_unique_idx&quot;
-- DETAIL:  Key (LEAST(name, alternate), GREATEST(name, alternate))=(bar, foo) already exists.
```